# C function decoration/polymorphism

Tags: c, pointers, polymorphism, decorator, abstraction

Is there some way I can execute code in the base function for all action types? I want to execute behavior common to all do_card actions.  In another words, I want to print the game state, but I want to avoid duplicating a printf in every individual do_card function, and instead write it once.  Is there a way to implement this in C?

```
struct CARD {
    int value;
    int cost;
    // This is a pointer to a function that carries out actions unique
    // to this card
    int (*do_actions) (struct GAME_STATE *state, int choice1, int choice2);
};
int do_card0(struct GAME_STATE *state, int choice1, int choice2)
{
    // Operate on state here
}

int do_card1(struct GAME_STATE *state, int choice1, int choice2)
{
    // Operate on state here
}

static struct cardDefinitions[] = {
    {0, 1, do_card0},
    {1, 3, do_card1}
};
int result = cardDefinitions[cardNumber].do_action(state, choice1, choice2);
```

Comment: There are no decorators in `c`. You could try to put the `printf` before calling some of these functions, if this is possible in your code. It looks like you have some `if` or `switch` statement - if the message is the same and applies for all functions, put it before calling any of them

Comment: This code avoids using a switch which was the goal.  I wanted to be able to add behavior across all the types but I guess its not possible in C.

Comment: You shuould try giving a more concrete example. I'm not sure what kind of code duplication you are trying to avoid here.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you *really* want to emulate polymorphism, you can, it just gets ugly.

```
typedef struct Card_t Card;
typedef struct 
{
   void (*print)(Card*);
   int (*do_action)(Card*, struct GameState*, int);
   /* other possibly card-specific functions here */
} CardMethods;

struct Card_t
{ 
  int value;
  int cost;
  CardMethods* vtab;
};

int stdAct(Card* this, GameState* st, int choice)
{
    this->vtab->print(this);  //do this card's specific print function.
    /* do common actions based on state&choice */
}

int specialPrint1(Card* this)
{
   stdPrint(this); //call parent print function
   printf("something special here");  //add behavior
}

CardMethods standardCard={stdPrint, stdAct};
CardMethods specialCard1={specialPrint1, stdAct};
CardMethods specialCard2={stdPrint, specialAct1};
CardMethods specialCard3={specialPrint2, specialAct2};
static struct cardDefinitions[] = {
 {0, 1, &standardCard},    
 {1, 3, &standardCard}, 
 {2, 3, &specialCard1},
 {2, 4, &specialCard2},
 /*...*/ 
}; 


cardDefinitions[i].vtab->do_action(&cardDefinitions[i], state, choice)
```

At this point you are doing most of what the C++ compiler does behind the scenes, you may as well just use C++.

Comment: ah yes i suppose i could make a list of functions and do pre/post behaviors..that would emulate decoration

Answer (score 3):

rather than calling do_action on each card, pass the card along with the other params to another function you define, have that call the do action method, then call the print state method or whatever

e.g.

```
//add a method like this
int process_card(CARD inCard, GAME_STATE *state, int choice1, int choice2)
{
    inCard.do_action(state, choice1, choice2);
    print_state(state);
}

//last line changes to 
process_card(cardDefinitions[card_number], state, choice1, choice2);
```

bound to be errors my C is rusty, but that's the jist I think.

Answer (score 2):

Is there something stoping you from simply creating subroutines like `print_game_state(GAME_STATE *)` and using them in the `do_card` functions?

```
int do_card0(...){
    print_game_state(...);
    //other stuff
}

int do_card0(...){
    print_game_state(...);
    //do different stuff
}
```

---

If this doesn't solve your problem, then create functions for each piece of card behaviour that varies between the classes and use these from the outer functions.

```
struct Card{
    int value;
    int cost;
    int (*f1)(struct card* self);
    int (*f2)(struct card* self);
};

void my_function(Card* card){
    card->f1(card);
    printf("something\n");
    card->f2(card);
}
```

Comment: Well, if it is a single and simple `printf`, this will not help. I guess eat_a_lemon is looking for something like Python's decorators..I guess.

Comment: You can't do python-style decorators cleanly in C. It doesn't have closures. (You can take inspiration from Python's explicit `self` variable and do everything  by hand though)

Comment: alright thanks for the info.  The bottom line is no I can't do it.

Comment: Since this is C and not C++, `f1` and `f2` should be changed to function pointers, not function declarations.

Answer (score 0):

If I'm understanding this question correctly, can you not simply create a common printing function that takes a certain set of attributes, and call that common print function from each of the `do_cardX` functions?

There are no templates in C, so you can't create a generic single `do_card()` function that would instantiate its argument types at the point of the function's call, and even if you could, you would have to still create some type of specialized print function that each function would have to call in order to print the specific game-state information you're wanting from each specific type of `do_card()` function.

Comment: game state printing is the same code across all types. The idea is to not duplicate this code in each do_card function.